# Discerning a component of a motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, part-identification

Here's a Yamaha XJ6N motorcycle:

[image]

But I was wondering what this component here was??

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like how you honed in on the actual part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this https://www.yamahamotorcyclespares.co.uk/genuineparts/13208/8/yamaha%20xj6n/oil%20cleaner?uid=0 parts manual (image not copied to protect copyright) its the oil cooler assembly.

Its also shown on the cooling images but not numbered https://www.yamahamotorcyclespares.co.uk/genuineparts/13208/6/yamaha%20xj6n/radiator%20&%20hose?uID=0.

The way I found this was to search on google (other search engines are available) for "Yamaha XJ6N online parts catalogue".  Once I had a search result set it was just a case for looking for components in roughly the same area and same shape as the one you are asking about.

Comment: Cheers! I'll see if I can find out through yamahamotorcyclespares.co.uk next time as well, it's good to know where to find these things out from!

Comment: Nice.  I've noticed that component popping up on bikes over the last decade or so.